written by/with quills and ink - Are letters written with or by pens?
Are letters written with or by pens??? I can't figure out the logic in Alex Jones' sentence:
'Basically the pint of green tea spilt all over the letter and because obviously letters back in the day were written
by, you know, quills and ink, the green tea fell on the letter and all of the writing fell off...'
(from 'Would I Lie To You?')

What is "Would I Lie to You?"?

@TimR - it's a British comedy panel TV show. Voting to close now.

The usage in the Alex Jones quote is unusual, and reflects the informal nature of the situation (British comedy TV panel show; not made clear in OP). In informal, off-the-cuff speech, people may use a 'wrong' word.
Usually, especially in formal speech or writing, although both words show how something can be done, they have different meanings. 'By' explains someone's action or who performed the action. 'With' explains what action was performed or what was used to perform the action. Ask yourself: did the pen write the letter by itself, or did a person use it to write the letter?

So Alex Jones believed that quills and ink used to write letters by themselves???

@Wittyhaire - see updated answer.

There are situations in which the distinction between agent and action or object comes under strain. "shot with a bow or arrow" sounds fine; "shot with a gun or bullet" doesn't, maybe because it's not idiomatic. News reports frequently talk of "killed by a bomb - or missile" rather than "with" (a difficult distinction when missiles choose their own targets). People are "struck by a machete", "hit by a brick (that fell from a wall) as opposed to "hit with a brick" that someone was wielding. And of course, people are struck by buses, not with them. even when they driven into a crowd.

@RonaldSole - Anglesey man tells of his hit and run horror - North Wales Live - -Llangefni - A MAN who was hit with a van by a neighbour with whom he had an ongoing dispute has spoken of his suffering...

@MichaelHarvey Clearly an ELL follower! Maybe it depends on the size of the object concerned. It might have been a very small van.

@RonaldSole Thank you. Where can I find more such borderline examples?

It's confused by the fact that "by pen", "by hand", "by fire", "by bicycle", etc, are common phrases. But if you're talking about specific pens, etc, use "with": "written by pen" but "written with a Victorian quill pen".

@Wittyhaire I don't know of any specific source. But I notice that it is increasing common in news reports to hear phrases like "killed by a rock", "knocked over by a bicycle". It seems to depend partly on whether the action was accidental (by a falling rock) or intentional ("with a rock" used as a weapon). In the use of drones and robots in warfare, the distinction between agent and instrument is likely to lost completely.

@RonaldSole - I'm reminded of the ancient English legal principle of deodand (from deo dandum  a thing to be given to God) under which a chattel which was shown to have caused the death of a 'reasonable creature' was forfeit to the Crown, to be sold and the money was put to pious uses, usually distribution in alms. Repealed in 1846, but I think I read somewhere that a steam-carriage that killed a man near Bath fell foul of it before that.
